# regular expression to remove string following

Tags: javascript, regex, gawk

```
http://www.example.com/product/9896341.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=VRM&utm_campaign=N&cid=vizuryjz&utm_content=&color=red&pid=9896341
```

in the above url, i need to remove text followed in `utm_source=google`, suppose if in `url utm_source="text"` i need to replace `"utm_source=text"` with `""`.

please guys help me for regular expression.

Comment: In JavaScript or using gawk?

Comment: @tom if possible, require in both.

Comment: This is more a feature request than a question about resolving some broken code. Just use online tools like http://www.regexr.com/ and learn to do your own.

Comment: @gillesec, i tried,but no luck in getting what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of gawk, I would recommend using gnu sed for this:

```
$ s="http://www.example.com/product/9896341.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=VRM&utm_campaign=N&cid=vizuryjz&utm_content=&color=red&pid=9896341"
$ sed -r 's/utm_source=[^&]+//' <<<"$s"
http://www.shopin.net/product/9896341.html?&utm_medium=VRM&utm_campaign=N&cid=vizuryjz&utm_content=&color=red&pid=9896341
```

This deletes `utm_source=` followed by anything up to the next ampersand.

Comment: i did like this (utm_?([^\&]+)?&) can u check please

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```
    utm_source=[^&?=]*
```

javascript

```
    your_url.replace(/utm_source=[^&?=]*/gi,"")
```

sed

```
    echo "http://www.shopin.net/product/9896341.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=VRM&utm_campaign=N&cid=vizuryjz&utm_content=&color=red&pid=9896341" | sed s/utm_source\=\[\^\&\?\=\]\*//g
```

Comment: i did like this (utm_?([^\&]+)?&), can u check please

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?